# Issue with saving form values in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

I am trying to save values of two different forms in a single array and have to send them to a server using POST. Right now, I have hardcoded an array into my *services.ts* and I am trying to push values of an array from my *.ts* into that array. The problem is that when I save the form the data from that one particular form is forwarded to the array in services. I tried using the save method in *submit* of both the forms but That just creates 2 objects, whereas, I need One object with the other one nested inside of it. Here is the class I am using :

```
export interface Mod {
    id : number ,
    name? : string,
    clauseList? : Clause
    country? : string;
    company? : string;
    process? : string;
}

export interface Clause {
    cName? : string,
    cid? : number,
    desc? :string,
    // pc : number,
    parentC?  :number,
    id? : number,
    text? : Text
}


export interface Text {
    txt? : string,
    tid? : number
}
```

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtyurw) I cannot figure out the issue here, but in my local machine when I save the form a new object is created and displayed in the console.

Here is what I get in the console [demoImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2KRj.jpg) The object at [0] is the one I hardcoded and is the format I need the data in, the object at [1] is what I get on saving the forms.

Can anyone assist me with how to create a new object with the required elements in it?

**Please read the readme.txt in the Stackblitz demo to get a better understanding of what I need help with**

Comment: Is the issue that you want the final object in the array `finalPostArray` to be only key value pairs and that it should not have any nested objects? For eg: something like  `finalPostArray = [ { a : 1 }, { b : 2 }, { c : 3 }]`?

Comment: the final object should be nested like the object at index 0 in the demoImage above. name, country, company, process and the clauseList element which is an array and then the same for text inside clauseList. The file mod.ts is kinda the reference. . I am trying everything but nothing helps

Comment: Included an answer; I believe that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, mate. Can you take a look at line 70 (ts file) of [this] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt9oxu) and let me know how to save values of mergedObj in component.ts to finalData in services.ts

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `this.sendtoService(this.finalPostArray);`? Also, if the answer below worked for you do consider accepting/upvoting the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `addFilter(...)` you may simply do:

```
addFilter(filter: NgForm) {
   this.mergedObj['filterKey'] = filter.value;
   filter.reset();
   console.log("filterAdded : : ", this.mergedObj)
}
```

Thereby, we define a *key* (which can be any string) to hold a value that is the current `filter.value` object.